# osm2po traffic signals -128

Tags: osm2po

Using osm2po to extract traffic signal in the vertices used to provide the value 1 in the clazz column of the vertex table:

[Add vertices costs to postgresql routable network](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80144/add-vertices-costs-to-postgresql-routable-network)

For some reason I keep getting the value -128 now. Is that supposed to be like this?

Comment: Can you give me a bit more background info? -128 looks like a barrier.

Comment: In the osm2po.conf I've enabled the following line: postp.1.class = de.cm.osm2po.plugins.postp.PgVertexWriter. When I look at the data the only values are 0 and -128.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the problem by enabling

nodeClazz.1.name=TrafficSignals
nodeTagResolver.class=de.cm.osm2po.plugins.routing.TrafficSignalsNodeTagResolver

in the OSM2PO-Routing section

now both barriers and traffic signals (1,-128) are written